# How does one add Gesture Recognizers in a sprite kit scene

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I know the usual way & it works in the view controller but not in the scene

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *longPanGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panRecognized:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:longPanGesture];
```

I then implement the selector, but it is never called. I then moved the same code into the view controller for my scene & the selector was called.

My question is how do you add a gesture recogniser to a sprite kit scene?

Comment: What is your question ? Where is your code?

Comment: add it to: self.scene.view

Comment: @LearnCocos2D adding it to the scene does not work either

Comment: I had the exact same problem.  Try adding the `UIGestureRecognizer` in the `UIViewController` that contains your `SKScene`.  You can set the target to your `SKScene`, but you must call `addGestureRecognizer:` from the UIViewController.

Comment: per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040347/uipangesturerecognizer-in-skscene, I had to add the gesture recognizer in didMoveToView. Adding it to initWithSize caused the selector to never fire