# How would I change my image if there is no touch?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a node thats in the center of the screen and can go to the left with a tap on the left side of the screen and right if theres a tap on the right side of the screen. I added a `SKTexture` so that if I press on the left the image will be a node facing the left and if I tap on the right the node will face to the right.

How would I make it so when Im not tapping the screen the image faces the screen? I made the image already but I don't know how I would code this.

```
let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
if location.x < CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) {
    hero.position.x -= speedOfTouch
    hero.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "lefthero")
    AudioPlayer.play()
} else {
    hero.position.x += speedOfTouch
    hero.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "righthero")        
    AudioPlayer.play() 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're implementing your code in your touches began method to make the hero face the side of the screen that was tapped, and if this is the case, resetting the hero to face the user (screen) is as easy as setting that image when the user stops touching the screen.

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)

    hero.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "screenFacing")
}
```

Note that if you're using any logic in touches began to determine how the number of fingers on screen should effect your hero's state, you should implement the same in touches ended.

Comment: It works thank you. I have one more question if I wanted to do a long press instead of a tap how would I do that.

Comment: @swifter22 Glad to help and there are a couple ways to do that. You could either fire up a timer in touches began with a rapid repeat interval to continue to move your hero as long as the user has their finger on screen, and cancel the times when touches end, or you could implement a [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/) on your scene's `view` and not have to deal with touches began/ended/etc at all.

Comment: I put this code in the touchesBegan and dont know where to go from here              let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "viewLongPressed:")

Comment: @swifter22 You wouldn't want to put it in one of your touches methods because you won't have a reference to the scene's underlying view, and because the gesture won't be added until the user touches the screen. You're going to want to add the gesture in the scene's `didMoveToView:` method as I described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19040392/716216). (answer is in Objective-C, but the concept is the same in Swift) Then use the `view` parameter as the view that you add the gesture to.

Comment: okay I added this to the didMoveToView. How would make the touch work when I press on the left and right? Thanks.     let longPress =  UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "viewLongPressed:")
        longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
        longPress.numberOfTapsRequired = 0
        longPress.numberOfTapsRequired = 0
        longPress.allowableMovement = 15